# How to toggle multiple divs?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a slideToggle for multiple divs but I must be doing something wrong because it isn't working. The hidden content doesn't show when I click the button. Also, I want the button to use ↑ when the content is being shown.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".show_hide").click(function() {
    $(this).parent(".title").next(".toggle").slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.toggle {
  display: none;
}

.show_hide {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 class="title">Heading 1<button class="show_hide" type="button">&#8593;</button></h2>
<div class="toggle">
  <p>content goes here</p>
</div>
<h2 class="title">Heading 2<button class="show_hide" type="button">&#8593;</button></h2>
<div class="toggle">
  <p>content goes here</p>
</div>
<h2 class="title">Heading 3<button class="show_hide" type="button">&#8593;</button></h2>
<div class="toggle">
  <p>content goes here</p>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ucx4asm2/

Comment: You didn't include jQuery in the fiddle or the snippet. If you do that the code works fine. See an updated version of your fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/9dL53z62/) and also the edited question. Voting to close as a typographical error

Comment: `F12` to open your Developer Tools, and go to Console.  This will show you any errors your javascript may encounter and should be your first thing you check when you have an issue.  Long before you make a StackOverflow question.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't added the jQuery library to the jsfiddle, by adding the library the code you provided will work.

If you want the button's arrow to change on click you could use the .text() method with a ternary statement, try and see if it's what you wanted.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".show_hide").click(function(){
    $(this).parent(".title").next(".toggle").slideToggle();
    $(this).text(function(i, text){
      return text === "↓" ? "↑" : "↓";
    });
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bgufwn5c/7/